# Gauges for Compact Framework Applications

Tags: compact-framework, dashboard, gauge

Can anybody recommend gauge components for Compact Framework applications?

The only gauge toolkit that I've found so far is Perpetuum's [Instrumentation Widgets for PDA](http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Instrumentation-Widgets-for-PDA.aspx).  Perpetuum's gauges aren't visually appealing to me and also seem to be supported only up to .NET CF 2.0.  Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one alternative is in smart device framework. http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/

RoundGauge in OpenNETCF.Windows.Forms It isn't very fancy though so it may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out OpenNETCF's option to me.  It wasn't what I was looking for, either, but at least now I know that the correct answer is "There aren't any good looking gauges for Compact Framework."